# Create the [nebula-graph] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

Can someone please help create the [nebula-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nebula-graph) for me?

**How the tag helps in categorizing and finding relevant questions**

Nebula Graph is an open-source distributed graph database solution and questions would be specific to Nebula Graph rather than the broad graph database category.

I work with Nebula Graph and would like to help people who ask questions about it here. However, users are currently unable to tag their questions correctly with nebula-graph and I'm unable to subscribe to notifications for it.

We do have [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula/issues) and Slack channel for chat, but some users find Stack Overflow a better place to ask questions.

**Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate：**

- [How to get vertex ID in Nebula Graph by providing the value of one of its attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60313112/how-to-get-vertex-id-in-nebula-graph-by-providing-the-value-of-one-of-its-attrib)
- [Graph Database Nebula Graph insert record failed but query regular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59349983/graph-database-nebula-graph-insert-record-failed-but-query-regular)
- [Query using `FIND` and `INDEX` failed. How does Nebula Graph indexing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352722/query-using-find-and-index-failed-how-does-nebula-graph-indexing-work)

**Tag name:**

[nebula-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nebula-graph)

**Excerpt:**

Nebula Graph is an open source graph database solution. Use this tag for any questions that relate to using Nebula Graph as the database of your project. Any bugs or feature requests should be reported through the Nebula Graph GitHub issue tracker.

**Wiki:**

Nebula Graph is an open source distributed graph database solution.

Use this tag for any questions relating to using Nebula Graph as the database of your project. Any bugs or feature requests should be reported through the Nebula Graph [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula/issues).

Find more about Nebula Graph at https://nebula-graph.io

Comment: Question: I see the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60313112/how-to-get-vertex-id-in-nebula-graph-by-providing-the-value-of-one-of-its-attrib) you linked to is tagged [tag:nebula]. I assume that tag is wrong there and it should be retagged?

Comment: You are right. It should be retagged. nebula is another product. See its [tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nebula/info)

Comment: So you're saying that question should have both the [tag:nebula] tag *and* a new `nebula-graph` tag? If there's some overlap between the two maybe the wiki text should make it more clear what the difference are.

Comment: In case I was unclear in my first comment, I'm asking if that question should have the current nebula tag replaced with a new one, not if we should change the existing tag.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your first comment. The two products don't have any overlap between them. And the first question I linked in my question should be retagged as nebula-graph instead of nebula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and created the tag, hoping I won't get yelled at for it later. IMO [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59352722/query-using-find-and-index-failed-how-does-nebula-graph-indexing-work) is not a very good fit for the site but apparently the *"Too broad"* close reason has been removed recently so I'll just have to assume we're allowing questions like that now.

I wasn't aware there was a 20k rep limit for editing tag wikis, so that bit has to go through review.

Comment: I agree this question is not that specific. It is kinda like a practice of "answering your own question", which according to some posts ([this one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)) is encouraged here on Stack Overflow, no? Both blog posts were written back in 2012, tho. So I'm curious if that's still effective now?

Comment: @venegr: answering your own question is still encouraged, as long as the question itself meets all the usual requirements - there are no special dispensations for self-answered questions. As for "too broad": we still have "needs more focus", which is essentially equivalent.